# NGRX: How to call same service multiple time with different payload from inside effect

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, rxjs6

**I don't want to use forkJoin inside effect**

In my effect, I am getting one array of id's and with the help of those ids, I want to call service multiple times. 
and every time when I get a response I want to dispatch an action to update my store

```
@Injectable()
export class MovieEffects {
  loadMovies$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType('[Movies Page] Load Movies'),

     //here i am getting one array object via action,  e.g. = [{id: 1},{id: 2},{id: 3},{id: 4} ]
     //and here i want to call same service 4 time as per array length
     // every time when get response i want to dispatch one action with response payload

      mergeMap((action) => this.moviesService.getAll()
        .pipe(
          map(movies => ({ type: '[Movies API] Movies Loaded Success', payload: movies })),
          catchError(() => of({ type: '[Movies API] Movies Loaded Error' }))
        )
      )
    )
  );

  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private moviesService: MoviesService
  ) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a for each on your array of ids and call your service in that loop, creating and subscribing to the new observables and dispatching actions when they are done.

```js
    loadMovies$ = createEffect(() =>
      this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType('[Movies Page] Load Movies'),
        tap((action) => {
         action.payload.forEach(id => 
            this.movieService.getMovie(id).pipe(
                map(movie => this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.GetMovieSuccess(movie)),
                catchError(() => this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.GetMovieFail(id)))
              .subscribe();
        } 
       )
     ), {dispatch: false}
    );
```

I personally almost always use {dispatch: false} for my effects and dispatch the events manually as I don't like always having them at the end of the effect as well as often having some other issues with the syntax.

Comment: Hi @kaloyan, Can you please provide some 2 liner information about tap operator, where we need to use. actually tap I never used before. thanks in advance.

Comment: @NeerajShrimali compared to map, tap just does some operations without modifying the data that the observable produces. If you don't need to transform the data you can use tap. If you use map, do some operations and just return the input without transforming it, it is like you have used tap. Also in the pipe to the movieService it could be a tap instead of map, since the result of the map is not used.

Comment: I don't find this is a good answer because I find it missleading that there's a dispatch:false but, the effect does dispatch actions via the store.dispatch function. Also, it shouldn't be needed to call subscribe manually, this could lead to memory leaks.

Comment: @timdeschryver I am assuming that the service is a wrapper for httpClient and it is doing a GET request. In that case if you don't subscribe the request won't get executed. The {dispatch: false} while actually dispatching is a bit confusing I agree. But if you are trying to dispatch multiple actions you will need to do it manually anyways.

Comment: I'n not convinced, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59288225/10112124

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`merge`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/merge) for this.

```
loadMovies$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType('[Movies Page] Load Movies'),
    concatMap((action) => {
        return merge(
            ...action.payload.map(id => this.movieService.getMovie(id).pipe(
                map(movie => new fromStore.GetMovieSuccess(movie)),
                catchError(() => of(new fromStore.GetMovieFail(id)))
            ))
        )
    })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `map(movies => ({ type: '[Movies API] Movies Loaded Success', payload: movies })),` you need to return the action through which you're going to update the store.

Consider I want to update my store through the method update() which is in action and the reducer(where i'm updating the store data), I would do like:

```
loadMovies$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType('[Movies Page] Load Movies'),

    switchMap((action) => this.moviesService.getAll()
      .pipe(
        map(movies => new Actions.update()),
        catchError(() => of({ type: '[Movies API] Movies Loaded Error' }))
      )
    )
  );
```